# Inserting events on Google Calendar from React app

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api

I am trying to upload events to google calendar from my React app. I cannot connect to the api and always get errors. I cannot use the official documentation from Google as they do not provide an example in react

I have tried importing the gapi from both the window (inserting the script in the index.html file in the public folder and also importing the gaps from an npm package (gapi-script), I can get the gapi but I cannot connect to the api and insert the events

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';

var CLIENT_ID = ' 705250920598-1e9hjc80vo3afsjhpjjiu9hm0s1k0brd.apps.googleusercontent.com ';
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showAuthButton: false,
      showSignOutButton: false
    };
    this.initClient = this
      .initClient
      .bind(this);
    this.updateSigninStatus = this
      .updateSigninStatus
      .bind(this);
  }
  handleAuthClick() {
    gapi
      .auth2
      .getAuthInstance()
      .signIn();
  }
  handleSignoutClick() {
    gapi
      .auth2
      .getAuthInstance()
      .signOut();
  }
  handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }
  initClient(/****here you've had parameters that made config vars unaccessible*****/) {
    gapi
      .client
      .init({discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS, clientId: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES})
      .then(function () {
        console.log(window.gapi);
        // Listen for sign-in state changes. ************* to access instance method you
        // have to use `this.updateSigninStatus`
        window
          .gapi
          .auth2
          .getAuthInstance()
          .isSignedIn
          .listen(this.updateSigninStatus);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

      });
  }
  updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
       //listUpcomingEvents(); insertNewEvent();
      console.log("api signed in");
    } else {

      console.log("api signed out");
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleClientLoad();
  }
  render() {
    let authButton = <button
      id="authorize-button"
      onClick={this
      .handleAuthClick
      .bind(this)}>Authorize</button>
    let signOutButton = <button
      id="signout-button"
      onClick={this
      .handleSignoutClick
      .bind(this)}>Sign Out</button>
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.showAuthButton
          ? authButton
          : null}
        {this.state.showSignOutButton
          ? signOutButton
          : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

I expect to be able to connect and log on the console api signed in instead I get uncaught exception: [object Object]

Comment: Can you use gapi from one place only like window.gapi and check?